# Android. How detect fullscreen app?

Tags: android, fullscreen, detect, statusbar

I need to detect when running full screen application. (The status bar is hidden).
How can this be accomplished?
Thank.

Comment: It is you who sets up the full screen by setting up an activity theme. What do you mean?

Comment: you wana make app/service/smth which can detect if **other app** is running in full screen? ... it can't be done

Comment: I need detect other fullscreen app. Howe made my app fullscreen i know.

Answer (score 3):

As of api11 there is now a way to detect that using a [View.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener%29)

The listener interface documentation notes the following:

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the status bar changes visibility. This reports **global** changes to the system UI state, not what the application is requesting.

I don't know if there's a way to do it prior to Honeycomb.

Answer (score -1):

You can figure out if your Activity is running fullscreen via `getWindow().getFlags()`.

Answer (score -2):

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Put in in your onCreate() method.

Answer (score -3):

i would say use flags like given below

```
if(getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)){
// your code goes here

}else{
// comes to this section
}
```